# Translating ASP Classic Email Code to C# ASP.NET Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp-classic

I have a couple of Classic ASP pages which send an email through the local user's Lotus Notes email client. The script basically grabs the user's database file and sends email through it. This works fine, but now I need to migrate the whole thing over to ASP.NET instead. (Using .NET Framework 4.0, by the way.)

The problem is, the code I have (which I found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600262/creating-fields-in-lotus-notes-document)) works great when I run it on my development machine, but when deployed to a server, it can't find the user's database. I want to basically run this particular subroutine as a script on the page so it won't be called from code behind, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Installing Notes on the server isn't an option, and I'm not permitted to use SMTP to do this through our servers. I can use Google's SMTP server, with a Gmail account, but if the traffic on that triggers some sort of "You're a business user, so here's your monthly bill" thing, that's not an option either. We also don't want to have our Gmail box tagged as a spam source or something, so I've hesitated to use Gmail as SMTP. (I'm willing to do that if the above conditions are going to clear, but at this point, we're sending and receiving hundreds of emails a day through the Notes client and the volume will only increase.)

So I get an ugly yellow screen of death whenever the button to send the email is clicked. My first attempt was in an ASP.NET web application with a code behind page, but I can't get this to work when I test it on a server. I can use the older, single-page format (we're still running Windows 2K3 Server right now, but that will be upgraded soon), but I still would like to know if there's a more modern solution to do this.

How can I make this particular script run on the page on the client, like the Classic ASP script does? Is there some technique I'm missing?

Here's the email code; it's called from a button click on the .aspx page.

```
    static void SendEmail()
    {

        // code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600262/creating-fields-in-lotus-notes-document'

        // create/initialize a notes session
        NotesSession sess = new NotesSession();
        sess.Initialize("database_Name");

        // get the database (?)
        NotesDatabase ndb = sess.GetDatabase("", "nsffile.nsf", false);

        // get the username
        string username = sess.UserName;

        // create the document to send
        var doc = ndb.CreateDocument();

        // set document properties
        doc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
        doc.ReplaceItemValue("SentTo", to);
        doc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", "MAILBOXNAME");
        doc.ReplaceItemValue("INetFrom", "MAILBOXNAME <mailboxname@domain.com>");
        doc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", sub);

        // remove the body and add it back as a rich text item
        doc.RemoveItem("Body");
        var rtitem = doc.CreateRichTextItem("Body");

        //  figure out how to include the attachments without magic string; Server.MapPath?
        rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", @"path\to\attachments\" + atch[0].ToString(), atch[0].ToString());

        // add the bod string to the rtitem
        rtitem.AppendText(bod);

        // now, replace the doc body field with the rtitem obj
        doc.ReplaceItemValue("Body", rtitem);

        // send and save
        doc.SaveMessageOnSend = false;
        doc.Send(false, to);

        // clear atch for consecutive sends
        atch.Clear();

    }
```

The variables are declared as class variables in the code behind page, and assigned values from the From, To, Subject, and Attachment text boxes (the attachment is a file picker). The body of the message is text in a textarea control.

Like I said, it all works if I run it on my local machine. From the server, the instant I click the Send button, the error indicates the page can't find a database to use. (Which is true.)

I'm not posting the .aspx code because it's a content page which uses a Master Page, and maybe that's the problem, but that's a lot of code to post. If it becomes important, I'll edit with the .aspx and the Master Page code.

---

EDIT: Here is the existing script on the ASP page. This works ONLY in IE, and in IE11, the site must be run in compatibility mode for this (and other scripts) to work. I should note, I am NOT the original page author, so I've been groping my way along trying to figure this stuff out, and replace it with (more) modern web applications when I can.

Anyway, here's the original script:

```
<script language="VBScript">

'on error goto 0: sendLNMail()
dim s
dim db
dim doc
dim rtitem
dim subj
dim bdy
dim recips(10) 
'File System Object Decs
Dim Addy
Dim Cnt 
dim fs
dim fName
dim path

sub sendLNMail()
    On Error Resume Next
    '     ////////////////////////////////
    'Get subject...if no subject, exit sub
    'subj = inputbox("Please enter a subject for your mail memo.","Email Subject Text")
    RepAdd = document.all("RepAdd").value
    Whoto = document.all("Whoto").value
    if Whoto = "" then
    msgbox "You need a Name that this e-mail will be sent to"
    exit sub
    end if
    AtAdd = document.all("AtAdd").value
    if  AtAdd  = "" then
    msgbox "You need an address that this e-mail should go to"
    exit sub
    end if
    subj = document.all("Subj").value
    if subj = "" then
    msgbox "You need a subject"
    exit sub
    end if
    'Get body text...if no body text, exit sub
    'bdy = inputbox("Please enter text for your body mail memo.","Email Body Text")
    bdy = document.all("bdy").value
    if bdy = "" then
    msgbox "You need body text"
    exit sub
    end if
    set fs = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if fs Is Nothing then
    msgbox "Could Not Create FileSystemObject",16,"File System Object Error."
    endMe
    exit sub
    end if 

    '     ////////////////////////////////

    set s = createobject("Notes.NotesSession")
    if s Is Nothing then
    msgbox "Could Not Create A Session Of Notes",16,"Notes Session Error."
    endMe
    exit sub
    end if 
    'See if we can create the main object (session)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    msgbox "Could not create session 'Lotus Notes' from object"
    exit sub
    end if 
    set db = s.getdatabase(s.getenvironmentstring("MailServer",True),s.getenvironmentstring("Mailfile",true))
    'See if we can a handle on the mail file'     
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    msgbox "Could find or get a handle on the mail file"
    exit sub
    end if
    set doc = db.createdocument
    set rtitem = doc.createrichtextitem("BODY")

    Addy = AtAdd
    Cnt = 1
    Do Until Addy = ""
    If InStr(1, Addy, ",") <> 0 Then
    recips(Cnt) = Left(Addy, (InStr(1, Addy, ",") - 1))
    Addy = Replace(Addy, recips(Cnt), "")
    Addy = Trim(Right(Addy, Len(Addy) - 1))
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    Else
    recips(Cnt) = Addy
    Addy = Replace(Addy, recips(Cnt), "")
    End If
    Loop

    with doc
    .form = "Memo"
    .subject = subj
    .sendto = AtAdd
    ' the Principal field overrides the FROM name:
    ' (creates problems for Gmail recipients - removing "@domain.com" seems to resolve)
    '.Principal = "emailtouse@domain.com" 
    .Principal = "EMAILALIAS"
    '.replyto = RepAdd
    .replyto = "EMAILALIAS@domain.com"
    '.blindcopyto = "emailaddress@domain.com"
    '.copyto = 
    .body = bdy
    .postdate = Date
    .savemessageonsend = True
    end with
    doc.visible = true
    doc.send false, recips
    Call doc.Save(True, False)

    'if we made it this far, alert the user 
    '     the mail memo has been created and sent
    msgbox "Your message has been created and sent." & chr(13) & "Thank you.",64,"Message Sent Notification."
    endMe

end sub
```

(...)

---

Where I've inserted the ellipsis (...), there are several more routines which are more or less identical to this one (messages displayed are different, and one allows adding an attachment to the email) before a subroutine closes and disposes the objects.

Hopefully, this bit of code will help identify how this works currently, and how the replacement routine will need to be written.

Any and all insights welcome, and thanks again.

Comment: "`I would like to know if there is a more modern solution to this.`" The modern solution is to use your org's SMTP servers.

Comment: Additionally, you say installing notes on the server isn't option, but there's almost no way similar old ASP classic code could have worked on your old server unless Notes was installed there, too.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, nope, incorrect. There is not now and has never been Notes on the server, period, end of the story. Sorry. And the page loads up in the user's browser and sends email through THEIR client, including the document in their Sent folder. So it does work in ASP classic.

Comment: Did it only run using IE, with perhaps a special plugin? This is something that web browsers are specifically designed to protect against. Back end code runs on the server and doesn't get to see files that live on the end users' machines. The link you provided shows vba code, which can work because it runs in office on the local machines. ASP Classic is vbscript running on a server. That's why it works when you test on your machine: because in that situation the end user machine IS the server.

Comment: Perhaps post your existing classic asp code as well.

Comment: @JonP - sorry, I wasn't in the office yesterday and didn't see your comments until today. I'll update the question with the existing code today.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - no special plug-in, but yes, it ONLY works in IE; and in IE11, we have to run the site in compatibility mode to make it work. I've yet to find a C# or JavaScript version which will run in Firefox or Chrome. Thank you for the insight. I've updated the question with new information; maybe that helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to convince someone to let you use your org's smtp server. The technology used here was retired because of security concerns. You won't get the same scheme to work again. The best you might  be able to get is a complicated mailto: link.

Comment: ...though you may find this link useful as a way to host .Net code in a browser: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31429/Embedding-a-NET-WinForms-Application-in-an-Interne (but it isn't well supported any more :( )